# Surface equation for a triangle when vertices are given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, surfaces

How to find equation for surface of a triangle when vertices are given?

Such as when vertices are $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

[image: surface]

Surface given by $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: I suppose "surface" here is "area"...?

Comment: No. The equation of the colored surface.

Comment: Your colored "surface" is just a bidimensional triangle....or am I missing something?

Comment: @DonAntonio In the example give, the answer would be "$x+y+z=1$".

Comment: @TrevorWilson, I still don't get it: that eq. is a plane's, and we're shown its intersection with $\;x,y,z\ge 0\;$ , so what is then **actually** been asked here?

Comment: @DonAntonio How to go from a set of vertices (perhaps assumed to be on the $x$, $y$, $z$ axes respectively) to the equation for a plane that intersects them all?  The equation is an _answer_ to an example problem.

Comment: Oooooh! Well, that makes more sense *now*, indeed...

Answer (score 1):

The set of points of the triangle with given vertices is given by its convex closed hull:

$$T = \{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3|a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 1,     a_1,a_2,a_3 \geq 0\}$$
where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the vertices. Notice that this generalizes to more vertices and also works for higher dimensions.